# Backbone pagination 10 at a time

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Im building an pagination in backbone. The problem is that the amount of pages has grown and are now that many that it ruins the layout of the site. So i want to implement a functionality where i can render lets say the first 10 pages and then with a next/prev button control which page numbers should be shown. But always only show 10 pages like so:

< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 >

< 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 >

So now i append this to my pagination (its all pages)

```
    updateTotal: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.totalModel.fetch({

            success:function(model,response) {
                var total = response.data; //all iems
                var p = total/self.perPage;
                var r = total-Math.round(p)   
                self.pagination = _.template($("#pagination_template").html(), {
                    pages:Math.ceil(p)
                });
                self.render();
            }
        });
    },
```

This is how i print it out in html (underscore.js)

```
    <script type="text/template" id="pagination_template">
        <section class="pagination">
            <ul>
                <% for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++) { %>              
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-offset="<%= i*9 %>" data-page="<%= i+1 %>">
                            <%= i+1 %>
                        </a>
                    </li> 
                <% } %>
            </ul>
            <div class="paging prev">&#9668;</div>
            <div class="paging next">&#9658;</div>
        </section>
    </script>
```

I have a variable the represents the current page and i know the total amount of pages. But i dont know how to implement this that i describes as my problem.

Anyone knows how to do this and can come with an example? Would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
    updateTotal: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.totalModel.fetch({

            success:function(model,response) {
                var total = response.data; //all iems
                var p = total/self.perPage;
                var r = total-Math.round(p);
                var c = ... // current page
                self.pagination = _.template($("#pagination_template").html(), {
                    pages:Math.ceil(p),
                    current: c
                });
                self.render();
            }
        });
    },
```

And the html

```
    <script type="text/template" id="pagination_template">
        <section class="pagination">
            <ul>
                <% 
                var renderPage;
                for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
                    renderPage = false;
                    if (pages < 10) {
                        renderPage = true;
                    } else {
                        if (current <= 5) {
                            if (i < 10) {
                                renderPage = true;
                            }
                        } else if (current <= pages - 5) {
                            if ((current - 5) < i || (current + 5) > i) {
                                renderPage = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ((pages - 9) < i) {
                                renderPage = true;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    if (renderPage) { %>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" data-offset="<%= i*9 %>" data-page="<%= i %>">
                                <%= i %>
                            </a>
                        </li> 
                    <% }
                } %>
            </ul>
            <div class="paging prev">&#9668;</div>
            <div class="paging next">&#9658;</div>
        </section>
    </script>
```

That will print the current page and the 4 pages before and after.

Comment: you can add some enhancements it's just the global algorithm

Comment: Hi, thank you! im on it right now. Unfortunately its says that "current" is undefined in underscore. Im not an underscore pro. Maybe some syntax missing in there?

Comment: have set the `var c = ... // current page` ?

Comment: Yes. And i got undefined. Even when i tried to just set it to some int (in case my actual currentPage where undefined) but i still get undefined.

Comment: Try this `current: c || 1` so if the current page is undefined it's initialized to 1.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Now the current get set. Now it renders correct amount of pages but the numbers that gets printed is wrong tho. if "current" is lets say 18 it should render 14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22. And so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I missed up a condition :) change this `if ((current - 5) < i || (current + 5) > i) {` by `if ((current - 5) < i && (current + 5) > i) {`